# Angular merge/join/combine two subscribes

Tags: angular, dynamics-365

I need to customize the Dynamics365 Event Portal home page, where I try to add Speakers (model) to each Event (model) in a list of Events. The list of Events is calling loadPublishedEvents() in the home.component.ts:

```
private loadPublishedEvents() {
    this.isLoading = true;       
    this.eventService.getPublishedEvents().subscribe(
        events => {
            this.allEvents = events;
            this.filteredEvents = events;
            this.isLoading = false;
        },
        (error: LocalizableError) => this.handleErrorResponse(error)
    );
}
```

Now for each Event, I want to add the Speakers of that Event. First I've extended the Events model by adding `speakers: Speaker[];`

There is also a page with the Event details, where the Speakers are displayed per Event. This detail page is calling loadSpeakers() form speakers.component.ts:

```
private loadSpeakers() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.eventService.getSpeakers(this.readableEventId).subscribe(
        speakers => {
            this.speakers = speakers;
            this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
                const selectedSpeakerId = paramMap.get(EventQueryParameterNames.SpeakerId);
                this.selectSpeakerById(selectedSpeakerId);
            });
            this.isLoading = false;
        },
        (error: LocalizableError) => this.handleErrorResponse(error)
    );
}
```

I there a way to combine these two?

I must say, I'm new to Angular and Google did not get me to the right answer so far (or I didn't implement it right, which is more likely...).

Comment: A subscribe inside a subscribe is a red flag. SwitchMap is your friend..

Comment: Yes, I know by now that I cannot have a subscribe in a subscribe, but I don't know how to use SwitchMap in my case....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combineLatest` of `rxjs`.

So, you can pass array of observables as parameter and get all results altogather.

Example:

```
combineLatest([firstMethod(), secondMethod()]).subscribe(
   results => {
      // accessing results
      const firstMethodsResult = results[0];
      const secondMethodsResult = results[1];
   }
);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't want two lists of results. I need one list of Events, where in each Event I have a list (array) of Speakers. Or maybe your answer is not clear to me...

Comment: Did you try piping `mergeMap` to flatten them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using mergeMap:

```
  private loadPublishedEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.eventService.getPublishedEvents().pipe(
      mergeMap(event => from(event).pipe(
        mergeMap(ev => this.eventService.getSpeakers(ev.readableEventId)),
        toArray()
      ))
    );
  }
```

I created a simplified stackblitz for this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ivjn1g